# What can I do about my bay window? There is a bobbly layer of cement which is not holding. Should I shotblast?

Tags: painting, exterior, stone

I have a large bay window which is covered in some kind of bobbly rendering. This is coming off badly. The top layer has not bound to the bottom layer. I have a choice between patching this up, or stripping away the paint / rendering completely, and then repainting, or even leaving bare. I have considered shotblasting to remove it. I don't know what the stonework is like beneath (I presume it is sandstone). Neighbouring houses do not have rendering (there is paint only), and it looks much nicer. Any thoughts?

[image: paint coming off]

[image: close up of paint]

[image]

Comment: Is it possibly concrete underneath, as opposed to natural stone?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - it would be most unusual on that style of architecture. Looks like pretty authentic London Victorian [even if it's not in London]

Comment: @Tetsujin Just trying to figure out why they would cover up real stone with that bumpy stuff.

Comment: _How_ to remove the stucco(?) coating is an on-topic question. Even the choice between repair/replace is probably on topic. _Which_ you should do is not on topic as that's opinion/decorating advice. Please edit to be more specific about what you're asking.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - it was a 'fashion' thing, 50s through 70s… pebble-dash, stucco, Artex everywhere. My father in law was a plasterer/renderer, he always said he spent the 60s & 70s being paid to put this on everything & the 80s & 90s being paid to take it all off again ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this UK? It looks like someone has used Artex over a poor render. It's always a bad idea to render stonework like that - just look at all the old council properties that were pebble-dashed in the 50s - worse still with an interior product.

First water gets in, then it freezes; rinse & repeat until the surface blows off and your original surface is totally destroyed. Not helped by the fact that every time someone repaints it, they're not getting right back underneath where the real damage is being done.

Because of what appears to be two different layers of 'render' you might get lucky & the soft stuff has taken the brunt of the damage. What I can see of the stone underneath looks like it may have got away with it to some extent.

You really need to get all that off… the trouble is going to be that you are going to have to patch & paint depending on the condition of the stonework underneath.

Shot-blasting or perhaps a needle gun would do it - you're going to have to keep gouging at it until you get far enough back to reach whatever is still solid. The surface may be powdery &/or flaky.
An exterior-grade filler, a lot of sanding, then several coats of good exterior paint. Repaint every few years to try prevent it happening again. If you stay on top of it, it's not a task you'll have to repeat.

Use the opportunity to mastic around those window frames too; it will look tidier painted over.

Comment: Great. Thanks for advice.